# Google Fonts: Which is faster? rel="preconnect" or WebFontLoader?

Tags: css, webfonts

For several months I have been using the Google WebFontLoader Javascript code to asynchronously load Inter and Nunito fonts from Google Fonts:

```
WebFontConfig = {
    google: {
      families: ["Inter:300,400,500,600,700", "Nunito:500"]
    }
  };
  
  (function (d) {
    var wf = d.createElement("script"),
      s = d.scripts[0];
    wf.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.28/webfontloader.js";
    wf.async = true;
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })(document);
```

But I have no doubt in which one is faster loading. Will it be using preconnect in the HTML? Thanks in advance.

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;600;700&family=Nunito:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: JS will always be slower, because browser has to initialize JS code, create objects in memory and only than start downloading resource.